# why my installation folder where I installed exe, dll required data to be used by application is dependent

Tags: .net, wpf, setup-project

I am developing wpf application, my installation saved all required data(dll, exe etc) to some folder on drive(I have specified the Default Path so). When I change this folder(For security purpose I am applying CLSID) application wont find the folder and reinstall it with the same folder and data into it, that means my installation is dependent on the folder. Why it is so? how to make it independent so that any change into the folder should make run application properly? I am using visual studio installer to create setup.Please help me.

Comment: Do you change the folder during or after installation? Does the install register anything in config files or in the registry?

Comment: thanks Erno de Weerd for your reply. Actually I am changing folder path by appending CLSID key to the existing path, but I am not doing entry in registry

Comment: Do you change the folder path during or after installation?

Comment: After Installation I am changing folder path
C:\\xyz to c:\\xyz.{132edafg23w34erer}

Comment: Could you explain how renaming the folder makes it secure?

Comment: create folder on c drive(C:\\Erno) then go to cmd and go to c:\\ type this command as it is
'rename Erno Erno.{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}' and watch out your folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30544/discussion-between-rahul-saksule-and-erno-de-weerd)

Comment: Ah, now I understand
You should have mentioned that in the question
My guess is that by locking the folder you are making it impossible for the user to access it. No wonder windows can't access it.

Comment: Please help me to sort out this problem

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Apparently you are trying to [secure the folder](http://www.onlinehowto.net/how-to-lock-and-unlock-a-folder-using-simple-bat-files-in-windows/1821).

You succeeded.

The user can no longer access it and cannot run programs in it. That is not a bug, it is a feature. Looks to me like you are complaining that when you lock the folder, you can no longer access the folder...

---

According to the comments you change the folder **after** installation.

### What might go wrong

When installing an application the application will be registered in the registry to it is possible to uninstall it.

Additionally, components of the application could be registered so they can be found during execution.

Also, during setup, it possible to use the install path in (custom) actions that write to configuration stores (database, registry, config files, ...) and thereby make the application dependent on these settings.

Shortcuts in the startmenu or on the desktop also point to the old location. So when starting the application using such a shortcut might cause windows to check/run the setup because it cannot find the application.

Finally, if you associated a file extension with the application and start the application by opening a file, the registration of the application will be broken too.

### How to fix this

First of all: do **not** change the folder name after setup. It will break all dependencies I mentioned above. Changing the folder name does **NOT** provide security in any way.

Either run the setup and install the application in the correct folder by having the user enter the correct folder name (including the CLSID) or append the CLSID in the setup by modifying the setup folder after the user entered the path.

Comment: I tried this trick also: In Application folder's DefaultLocation If I provide path with appended CLSID(i.e. instead of C:\\xyz I used C:\\xyz.{q345rt234tdsfg24t45g}) then after installation,application won't get open when click on the shortcut. Why it is happening?

Comment: Yes I checked this and my shortcut points to the correct exe which is included in the application folder

Comment: I have also tried one trick:I created new folder on target location and add all data to that folder and kept all necessary data required like .dll, .exe, .ico etc outside the folder so that to remove dependance of installation, but no use

Comment: Yes after Locking folder it cannot accessible from outside, but can be accessible programmmatically, I am using this and it is working fine,but what the problem is that my shortcut not able to do so hence installing each time after I lick

Comment: That is not something you can fix. It is locked so the shortcut cannot access it.

Comment: Although it is locked but my application is able to access it when runs for first time as a PostBuildEvent, and also when I run application via Visual studio then also it is working fine. Only the problem is while click shortcut then either it won't open or it installs again

Comment: or else if you can provide some other solution to lock/unlock folder within the application really appreciable.